# React Context API: uanble to override Provider value

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to write a reusable React component, with its own [context](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/context/), and I am stuck on something that seems rather rudimentary.

In the simplified example below, I am overwriting the setMessage when instantiating the `ToastContext.Provider`.  When I try to call the context's setMessage downstream however, I am getting the default function called (which shows the console log) versus getting the updated value I was hoping for...

I'm not sure if this is a React thing or a NextJS thing or (most likely) a PIBCAM thing.  I fully acknowledge this is likely a dupe but I have been looking all day for a post that has been useful without luck.

**Control Code**

```js
export interface ToastStore {
    setMessage: (message: string) => void
}

export const ToastContext = createContext<ToastStore>({
    setMessage: (message: string) => { console.log(`Incorrectly trying to set message here: ${message}`) }
})

export function ToastProvider({ children }: { children?: ReactNode }) {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('Not Set')
    return (
        <>
            <ToastContext.Provider value={{setMessage}}>
                <div>Toast: {message}</div>
                {children}
            </ToastContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Consumer** *(part of of `{children}` begin injected into controller)*

```js
export const Some Control = ({ children }: any) => {
    const toastContext = useContext<ToastStore>(ToastContext)
    toastContext.setMessage('Here I am')!
    // ^ I would expect "Here I am" to show up in the Toast component's div, but instead
    // I get the console log message from the context's default value
```

Comment: Did you render `<ToastProvider />` anywhere?

Comment: Yah... that much I think I got correct... 

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <main>
        <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <ToastProvider>
             <TestControl />
          </ToastProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </main>
    </Provider>
  )

Comment: Hmmm, your question got me thinking.  in looking at my full project again, I may be having a challenge with nested contexts (the ToastProvider is layers above what's triggering it with another custom context in between).  I'm going to experiment a bit further.  Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

What turned out to be the problem, and I'm not sure why, was a path issue with the import statement.  I'm working in a monorepo, and the reference to the ToastContext was being made with a relative path instead of using the "default" export specified in the other project's  package.json main statement.  This is weird as heck, and not sure why, but changing the reference has everything working now.  Thanks to Mark for the reply.